# Find area enclosed by three functions

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, area

I'm trying to find the area enclosed by three different functions, but I'm having some difficulty as the dimensions are confusing to me.

The functions are:

$$y = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$y = 16x$$ 
$$y = \frac{x}{9}$$

I've graphed these functions and it gives me an interesting shape.
I've also calculated the points of interception as $(\frac{1}{4},4)$ and $(3,\frac{1}{3})$

[image]

My initial idea was to simply subtract all their areas between the bounds of their intercepts, but that isn't working.

$$\int \frac{1}{x} - 16x - \frac{x}{9} dx$$ from 1/4 to 3

What is the recommended method to calculate area here? Thank you for reading and all answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should basically try this:

> $\textrm{The required area} = \int_0^\frac{1}{4} 16x \, dx +
>  \int_\frac{1}{4}^3 \frac{1}{x} \, dx - \int_0^3 \frac{x}{9} \, dx$

Tell me if you don't understand the above statement.

The area, if you calculate it, will come out to be $\left(\ln 3+2\ln2\right)$.

Comment: Thank you! these are all very wonderful answers but I understood the best from this one.

Answer (score 2):

Split it up into sections: dividing them where the blue intersects the red. From $0$ to that intersection point, you only need to consider the area between blue and green.  Then, from the blue-red intersection to the red-green intersection point, you only need to find the area between the red and green curves.

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate a function, you will get the area under the curve. You are almost on the right path but just one mistake. By following your method, you are essentially subtracting an area which is part of both under blue and green curve **twice** (which is in the 3rd quadrant where both x and y values are negative).

An almost similar question is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290173/area-between-three-lines-curves). Follow the same method and lets us know how it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

You've basically got it except for *adding* the area under the red curve.

Area under blue plus area under red minus area under green.